# Kitchen-Docker specify image name for Dockerfile

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am currently using `kitchen-docker` driver for testing my cookbooks. Wondering how to specify a image name:tag for the image that is build by the `kitchen create` command.

**Here is my .kitchen.yml :**

```
---
driver:
  name: docker
  use_sudo: false
  dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
  remove_images: true
  privileged: true
  run_command: /usr/sbin/init

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  data_bags_path: 'data_bags'
  environments_path: 'environments'
  cookbook_path: "cookbooks"
  client_rb:
    environment: development

platforms:
  - name: centos-7
    driver_config:
      container_name: myapp
      instance_name: myapp


suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[web_server::default]
      - recipe[app_server::default]
    attributes:
```

Run the command:

```
kitchen create
```

Creates a docker image as `<none>` I would like to call the image as `mycompany/app`

```
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                             <none>              18e663ff7508        17 seconds ago      1.14GB
```

any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a way to do it.

you can actually pass the `build_options:` and `tag`. As shown in the code below.

**.kitchen.yml** (the full yml file is in the question above.)

```
platforms:
 - name: centos-7
   driver_config:
    dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
    build_options:
     tag: mycompany/myapp:latest
     rm: true
    container_name: myapp
    instance_name: myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for this, `kitchen-docker` doesn't use tags as it doesn't need them, it tracks the build image ID itself.